# why response.setIntHeader() function do not run?

Tags: java, servlets

**I have the following code in servlet**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet main</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet main at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
protected void doGet( request, response)
    {

   processRequest(request,response);
   response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);

    }
```

If I delete `processRequest(request,response)` then `response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5)`  works, but I do not remove then it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the headers before the body. so switch the order of procesRequest and reesponse.setIntHeader and it should work.